# Windows: Script copy pdf files from one folder to two other folders

Tags: powershell

I have a folder on a server 2008. It is populated by pdf files. Need to copy contents of the folder(only pdfs) to two other folders with deleting files that are being coped at the original source folder. Main concern is to make sure that I am only deleting pdf files that were copied and not any other files at the original location. If for some reason while coping a new pdf file came in into original source folder, want to make sure it does not get deleted. Can it run itself every 30 minutes without using task scheduler?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try something please but honestly your question is relevant